# Adjust plot scale in R markdown

Tags: r, ggplot2, r-markdown

How do I change the scale of a plot in R markdown? In other words, how do I make the output look more like to the plot on the bottom when I knit my HTML document?

````
---
title: "Test"
output: html_document
---

```{r}
data <- data.frame(x = 1:10, y = rnorm(10))
ggplot(data, aes(x, y)) +
    geom_point(size = 4)
````

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

For each code chunk in the curly braces at top you can set `fig.height` and `fig.width` which sets the output dimensions when knitting.

Comment: That seems to adjust the plot size relative to the page. I want to adjust the size of the plot features (text, lines, etc.)

Comment: Those things are related. As you shrink the plot, the text and geoms will have larger relative size. But you can also control those separately. E.g. `theme(text = element_text(size=35))` will modify all the text. You can also adjust other things in `theme()` like grid lines etc.